# Custom Background for list item

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android, android-drawable

I have a Custom list view. This list view is basically a chat list. For each list item i want to have a particular background , as shown in the picture. 
How to implement this background? Is it possible to draw this background using xml so that it adjusts to any size ?

[image]

Rectangle can be drawn using <shape> in xml file. But how to draw the whole thing? I don't mind the background color!

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an image, you should use a [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

If you want a shape, just create one and use the background attribute of your main layout